# json array into Ext js Grid

Tags: ajax, json, parsing, servlets, extjs

How can I retrieve json array returned from my servlet in my ajax request in order to put it into an ext js grid?
Note: My application always returns an empty grid!
This is my ajax request:

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'src/AccessServlet.java',
    method:'POST',
    success: function ( result, request ) {
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Data return from the server: '+ result.responseText);
    myData =Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
    console.log(myData);
    store.loadData(myData);
    },
    failure: function ( result, request) {      
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
    } 
});
 var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: [{name: 'name'},
       {name: 'id'},]
});
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [ {header   : 'Name', 
            width    : 60},
        { header   : 'id', 
            width    : 60},],
         height: 200});
        grid.render('grid');
         });
```

and this is my servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {
       response.setContentType("application/json");
     System.out.println("Right!!You are in servlet now !!!!! ");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // Output stream to STDOUT
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
    myObject.put("name","xx");
    myObject.put("id","123");
    System.out.println(myObject);
   JSONObject myRecord = new JSONObject();
    myRecord.put("name","yy");
    myRecord.put("id","12");
    System.out.println(myRecord);
    JSONArray myRecords = new JSONArray();
    myRecords.add(myObject);
    myRecords.add(myRecord);
    System.out.println(myRecords);
    }
```

my web.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ajaxWithServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>ajax.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
  <description></description>
<display-name>AccessServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>AccessServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>AccessServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>AccessServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/AccessServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Help me please!

Comment: Have you defined the grid? Is `store` the one configured for that grid? What is not working for you? Because basically what you are doing here should work.

Comment: Yes i have defined my grid, and store is the one configured for my grid!besides my servlet return successfully an json array!but the grid is always empty!!

Comment: What should i do?!I need your help please

Comment: Can you also post the JSON?

Comment: ok I posted my servlet code above!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the URL of your JsonDataStore. You can't access your servlet through the directory structure. Simply it won't work. Specify the application server URL of your servlet to url attribute in the DataStore. You should find this useful.

[Can't get jSon dataStore into ExtJS (Sencha Touch) chart: displays error "cannot read property 'length' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203872/cant-get-json-datastore-into-extjs-sencha-touch-chart-displays-error-cannot)

Ok. In your ajax request you have specified the url as 'url:src/AccessServlet.java'. This is you are trying to directly access the source file. It won't work because any Java source file can not be run unless compiled. Servlets are same. Besides you have to map your servlet in your web.xml file. When the web application is deployed servlet will be available through the url mapped in the web.xml. Use this url in the  ajax request. Another thing is that in your servlet you have to write the json object to the response. Use the PrintWriter instance for this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Comment: Im sorry but i didn't understand what you mean.Could you explain please?!

Comment: I had mapped my servlet in my web.xml from the beginning and I wrote my json object to the response as you said using a printWriter but still have the same problem.

Comment: Please post your web.xml as well

Comment: ok I will edit my post by adding my webxml file!!                Note:By using Firebug, it show this error: Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String