# drawing piechart using extjs from json file

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs

i've successfully drawn a pie chart using extjs with json values through ajax calling. but i couldn't be able to draw the same way by retrieving the json values from a json file  named **myjson.json**,

can anyone please tell me how to draw pie-chart by retrieving the json values from a json file (**myjson.json**) with the below code

my code is as given below

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 
    var getResources,getResources1;
    var flag=0;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        dataType : "json",
        url: 'getHSEXmatrix.action',
        params: {
        },
        success: function(response){
         getResources = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        createChart3(getResources);
     }
    });


var createChart3 = function(resources) {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
       fields: ['name', 'data'],
       data: resources
    });
    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: 'myExample3',
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['data'],
            label: {
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
            },
            title: 'No of actions',
            grid: true,
            minimum: 0
        }, {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['name'],
            title: 'Exclation Matrix'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            axis: 'bottom',
            highlight: true,
            tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 140,
                height: 28,
                renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data') + ' views');
                }
            },
            label: {
                display: 'insideEnd',
                field: 'data',
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
                orientation: 'horizontal',
                color: '#333',
                'text-anchor': 'middle'
            },
            xField: 'name',
            yField: 'data'
        }]
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What does `response` actually contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this stuff [**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203872/cant-get-json-datastore-into-extjs-sencha-touch-chart-displays-error-cannot**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203872/cant-get-json-datastore-into-extjs-sencha-touch-chart-displays-error-cannot)

1. run the sample on a web server as loading JSON files from the file system can sometimes cause problems.
2. Structure the json data as below

   ```
   {
       "data": [
           {
               "School": "Dukes",
               "wins": "3"
           },
           {
               "School": "Emmaus",
               "wins": "10"
           },
           {
               "School": "Maryland",
               "wins": "5"
           },
           {
               "School": "Virginia",
               "wins": "2"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Use the below data store

   ```
   window.store1 = new Ext.data.Store({
       model: 'Details',
       proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url: 'GetDataset.json',
           reader: {
               root: 'data',
               type: 'json'
           }
       },
       autoLoad: true
   });
   ```